# Convert string.Format method call to C# interpolated string

Tags: c#, string

I know that I should probably leave the codebase alone (principle: if it ain't broke...) but the one in question has a lot of calls to string.Format() and I'm intrigued by the new interpolated string support in C# 6.0 as it might make the {0} substitutions less error prone. My aim is to detect and remove execution paths that might have an unused parameter to string.Format() or - worse - an unsubstantiated reference to a parameter that doesn't exist (e.g. {1} if there's only only one parameter).

Do any tools or code snippets exist that might assist in converting all string literals from one format to the other? I'd settle for *.cs files to start, the XAML binding replacements could come later.

Would this exercise be relatively safe (i.e. is there some glaringly obvious flaw with interpolated strings that I haven't considered?)

Comment: Just one suggestion .. whichever tool you use, please add unit test before the change or if they are already there make sure you have not broken them after you make your changes :)

Comment: You could write your own DiagnosticAnalyzer with Roslyn framework.

Comment: ReSharper is capable of performing this sort of refactoring and analysis.

Comment: @Kyle I know Resharper supports this but is there a way to do it through Code Cleanup or is it only a Quick Fix? If there is a Code Cleanup setting I would be interested in how to set it up.